# Nuxt.js 500 NuxtServerError under docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js, nestjs

my system contains 3 dockers:

1. mongodb
2. api backend, built with Nestjs
3. web application, build with Nuxt.js
   the mongo and the backend seems to be working, because i can access the swagger at localhost:3000/api/.
   the Nuxtjs web app is failing, and i'm getting 500 Nuxtserver error.

```
Dockerfile (for the web app):
FROM node:12.13-alpine

ENV APP_ROOT /src

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 4000
```

```
docker-compose.yml:
version: "3"
services:
  # backend nestjs app
  api:
    image: nestjs-api-server
    container_name: my-api
    depends_on:
      - db
    restart: unless-stopped
    
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production
    ports:
      - 3000:3001
    networks:
      - mynet
    links:
      - db

  # mongodb
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: db_mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes: 
      - ~/data/:/data/db
    ports: 
      - 27017:27017
    
    networks:
      - mynet
   

  # front web app, nuxt.js
  web:
    image: nuxtjs-web-app
    container_name: my-web
    depends_on:
      - api
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 4000:4000
    environment:
      - BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/api
    command:
      "npm run start"

    networks:
      - mynet

    
networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

Looks like the nuxtjs app cannot connect to the api. in the log i see:

```
ERROR  connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
```

But why? the swagger (coming from the same api) works fine on http://localhost:3000/api/#/.
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

```
environment:
  - BASE_URL=http://localhost:3000/api
```

localhost in a container means inside that particular container. i.e., it will try to resolve port 3000 in `my-web` container itself.

Basically from front-end you cannot do container communication. May be you can communicate via public hostname or ip or you can make use of `extra_hosts` concept in docker-compose to resolve localhost.

Comment: thanks. that makes sense. so what should be the base_url for the web app? I have just tried this:  - BASE_URL=`http://api:3000/api`  where the first 'api' means the backend docker. no luck. in the console i see:  ERROR  connect ECONNREFUSED 172.22.0.3:3000

Comment: From front end you cannot do docker communication as it runs in browser. You should provide a hostname which can be resolved.

Comment: what do you mean? do you have an example, or link?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. The problem was in nuxtServerInit. This is a very special method on vuex, and it is running in the server. i called $axios from it, and i guess you can't do that.
once i commented that method, it's working fine.